# Django Sass Compressor django_libsass.SassCompiler: command not found

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-compressor, wagtail

I'm using a Django-Compressor Filter as part of Wagtail (Django variant CMS with super cool UI). Environment is Wagtail 0.2 + Python 2.7 + Django 1.6 + Virtualenv + FastCGI + Apache shared hosting.

Issue occurs when trying to access admin/login page of the CMS. Django shows an Error rendering template

```
    Error during template rendering

In template /home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/templates/wagtailadmin/skeleton.html, error at line 20
/bin/sh: django_libsass.SassCompiler: command not found
```

Line 20 of the skeleton.html is:

```
    <!doctype html>
    {% load compress %}
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"  lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-gb" }}"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"  lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-gb" }}"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"  lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-gb" }}"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"  lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE|default:"en-gb" }}"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <title>Wagtail - {% block titletag %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>

        {% block css %}{# Block defined for timing breakdowns in django debug toolbar - not expected to be overridden #}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700" /> 
19          
20          {% compress css %}
21              <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}wagtailadmin/scss/normalize.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}wagtailadmin/scss/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.verdant.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}wagtailadmin/scss/vendor/jquery.timepicker.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}wagtailadmin/scss/core.scss" type="text/x-scss" />
            {% endcompress %}

            {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body class="{% block bodyclass %}{% endblock %} {% if messages %}has-messages{% endif %}">
```

the precompiler in my settings.py, DEBUG is set to True:

```
COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = ( 
     ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'), 
)
```

**TRIAL AND ERROR #1**

I've tried changing to:

```
('text/x-scss', '/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_libsass {infile} {outfile}')
```

but that leads me to a dictionary update sequence element #0 error.

I have django_libsass & compressor installed, also tried `pip install libsass`, `ngm install lessc`, `pip install sass`, turning `DEBUG = False`, adding `COMPRESSOR_OFFLINE`, adding `COMPRESSOR_ENABLED` as suggested in other similar questions. Running `manage.py compress` returns the same error.

Have rechecked and site-packages and django_libsass are indeed on my sys.path

SassCompiler can be found in `~/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_libsass.py`

**TRIAL AND ERROR #2**

Re-checked that `sass` is installed and on my path.

Change code to:

```
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = ( 
     ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'), 
 )
```

Returns error:

```
Exception Type: FilterError
Exception Value:    
/bin/sh: sass: command not found
```

**TRIAL AND ERROR #3**

After reading this [feedly issue](https://github.com/tbarbugli/feedly_pin/issues/1), tried  `pip install compass` to no effect

**TRIAL AND ERROR #4**

Following gasman's comment, I ran python manage.py shell and tried to import SassCompiler It works with no errors.

```
 Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 18:34:29) 
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    (InteractiveConsole)
    >>> from django_libsass import SassCompiler
    >>>
```

**Full Traceback**

I do apologize if this question is getting too long.

```
Traceback:
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py" in render
  147.         return self.render_compressed(context, self.kind, self.mode, forced=forced)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py" in render_compressed
  107.             rendered_output = self.render_output(compressor, mode, forced=forced)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/templatetags/compress.py" in render_output
  119.         return compressor.output(mode, forced=forced)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/css.py" in output
  51.                     ret.append(subnode.output(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/css.py" in output
  53.         return super(CssCompressor, self).output(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/base.py" in output
  246.         content = self.filter_input(forced)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/base.py" in filter_input
  194.         for hunk in self.hunks(forced):
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/base.py" in hunks
  169.                 precompiled, value = self.precompile(value, **options)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compressor/base.py" in precompile
  226.                                 **kwargs)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_libsass.py" in input
  51.             return compile(filename=self.filename)
File "/home/username/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_libsass.py" in compile
  41.     return sass.compile(**kwargs)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

Comment: What error message (if any) do you get if you run `from django_libsass import SassCompiler` within `manage.py shell`?

Comment: I tried that and did not get any errors. I think the error kicks in within SassCompiler at the `sass.compile` line. Was worried my sass wasn't properly installed following Kevin's reply and had my hosting reinstall it & cython & libsass & compass. Also tried `gem install sass` which gives me a ruby folder with sass. Before that I had a sass.so in my site-packages folder.

Comment: @gasman, if it helps, I actually started an entire [blog](http://diaryofawebnoob.wordpress.com) chronicle of my wagtail installation process. most of my errors are listed there in detail

Comment: OK - the new error `'module' object has no attribute 'compile'` is different from the one you originally reported, so it looks like something has changed in your setup: it's now successfully finding django_libsass, but it looks like it's importing the wrong thing for the name 'sass'. Please try uninstalling all sass-related Python packages apart from libsass and django-libsass. If that doesn't make any difference, please run `import sass; sass` within `manage.py shell` and let me know what the output says.

Comment: gasman! it worked! I love you!

Comment: on a more serious note, if you'd repost as answer i'll set as accepted answer. What happened was I uninstalled everything else as you said, and `import sass; sass` pointed to `sass.pyc` but was still giving same attribute error. Deleting all the sass-related `.pyc` files solved that and I'm seeing the log-in page for the first time!

Comment: I did however, change one thing to remove the `/bin/sh: django_libsass.SassCompiler` error I was getting. I put `shell = False` in Compressor Filter's `base.py` hope that doesn't cause trouble down the road

Comment: OK, answered! The `shell = False` shouldn't matter... now that django-libsass is correctly installed, that line of code should (hopefully) never get run.

Comment: I've now put together a wiki page detailing steps to try when encountering this error: https://github.com/torchbox/django-libsass/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Reposting my comments as an answer, as requested...)

The original error: `django_libsass.SassCompiler: command not found`

meant that it was failing to import the django-libsass library. (django-compressor responded to that failure by trying to treat it as a shell command instead - django_libsass is not a runnable command, so this failed too, giving the actual error seen here.) The solution is to ensure that django-libsass is installed - it should show up in the output of `pip freeze`.

The second error: `'module' object has no attribute 'compile'`

meant that there was another package installed which defined a module called `sass`, and this was being loaded in place of the one we wanted, from the libsass package. The solution is to uninstall all sass-related packages apart from django-libsass and libsass.

Comment: Just an addition: django-libsass might have been installed correct but have an error during runtime that needs to be fixed. In my case is was outdated and incompatible to Django 3. Look for an error in the stack trace above `django_libsass.SassCompiler: command not found` and try to fix this first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem my Python-Django project and rvm. The problem is that the compress precompiler does not know which rvm to use. Solution is to add the ruby path to environ and tell the precompiler where to find sass in the settings.py file:

Like in my case  (just do `which sass` to find the path):

```
 environ['PATH'] = '/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:Users/username/bin'

 COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
 ('text/x-scss', '/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/sass --scss --trace {infile} {outfile}'),
 )
```

Hope that this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
/bin/sh: django_libsass.SassCompiler: command not found
```

Indicates that Django Compressor is trying to run `django_libsass.SassCompiler` as a shell command, and the script is failing to run.

That's because `django_libsass.SassCompiler` isn't a valid program that could be run from the command line.

Your best bet is to first install sass if you haven't already, by following the instructions on this page: http://sass-lang.com/install

Then change your code to:

```
 COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = ( 
     ('text/x-scss', 'sass --scss {infile} {outfile}'), 
 )
```

You'll have to be sure the `sass` command is on your path.

From the docs (http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS) the second part of your tuple is:

> The command to call on each of the files. Modern Python string formatting will be provided for 
>   the two placeholders {infile} and {outfile} whose existence in the command string also triggers the 
>   actual creation of those temporary files. If not given in the command string, Django Compressor will 
>   use stdin and stdout respectively instead.

Comment: strange, I have checked that I can import `sass` so it is on path. Tried changing code and get `/bin/sh: sass: command not found` which means it's still trying as a shell command?

Comment: There are two paths at work here - $PYTHONPATH, which determines the directories that python searches when you import, and $PATH, which determines what can be run from the command line.  The `sass` program is not a python library - it is a standalone program that can be run on your development machine.  If you are on the command line and you type `sass`, you will see that the command is not found.  Either install sass using the instructions at http://sass-lang.com/install or have your system administrator do so.

Comment: "...Indicates that Django Compressor is trying to run django_libsass.SassCompiler as a shell command, and the script is failing to run." - This is a red herring. Django-compressor first tries to interpret the string as a python module, and if that fails (as apparently it is doing here), it falls back on treating it as a shell command. It shouldn't be necessary to install a command-line Sass tool to use Wagtail - the django-libsass library should be handling it entirely on the Python side. (We've worked hard to minimise non-Python dependencies for Wagtail...)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django_compressor==2.4
pip install django-libsass
```

This worked for me, Also install latest of django-libsass.

Answer (score -2):

`pip install django_pyscss` will fix your issue.